# Changing values in array doesn't propagate into application

Tags: java, android, resources

- Goal: Demo activity displays list of String items in a list
- Dev. environment: Eclipse, android emulator as device
- Implementation: When activity is created, it stores String items from array defined in a xml resource file, and creates binding to ListView object via ArrayAdapter

Everything worked fine when I started the application. The list contained the items as expected.

**Issue**: 
However, I decided to change the values in the array definition in the xml file, and also the name of the array.

Naturally, I changed all occurences of the name of the array from the xml file to the new one in the code too. Now, when I *Run* the application again, I still see the old values in the list.

**What should I reset so the changes of the values become visible?**

So far, I tried this:

- application in emulator manually uninstalled, and then installed again via *Run*
- started emulator manually with option *wipe user data* checked
- Eclipse restart

Comment: Try cleaning your application. Eclipse is notorious for getting it wrong when working with the XML

Comment: Try cleaning and then rebuilding. Also, check that you don't have any errors in your XML files, which I think are not as obvious as Java errors.

Comment: Thanks.

You were right, all I had to do was to Clean the project.

Comment: @GiantMarshmallow - if you want to type up your comment as an answer we can get this one voted up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably changing the XML files through an external editor and not through Eclipse.
The build process checks whether there are changes in the project before creating a new APK.
If you change a resource / xml / source or anything outside of the Eclipse environment, you have to refresh the project (or the changed files) to allow the APk to be rebuilt.

Cleaning the project, as Pyrodante suggested, will achieve the same goal, as the APK will be rebuilt with the new files after cleaning.